# NSNumberFormatter different on device and simulator

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I have a UITextField, using this code, print the value on the label at the bottom and formatting it.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setUsesGroupingSeparator:NO];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
NSNumber *calcolo = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[value1 doubleValue]-[self.textfield.text doubleValue]];
formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:calcolo];
self.label.text = formattedString;
```

On the simulator (U.S.), the value is displayed correctly. On the device (IT), there is the comma on keyboard, but the value after the comma is always zero.
[image]

EDIT: This works

```
NSNumber *temporaryValue1 = [formatter numberFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",value1]];
NSNumber *temporaryTextField = [formatter numberFromString:self.textField.text];
NSNumber *calcolo = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([temporaryValue1 floatValue] - [temporaryTextField floatValue])];
formattedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:calcolo];
```

Comment: instead of the setDecimalStyle and setting the number of diigits etc. try [numberFormatter setPositiveFormat:@"###0.##"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the issue is your output. The issue is the input you get from `-[NSString doubleValue`]. That method doesn't honor the user's locale.

You should be able to use the formatter you made to convert `self.textField.text` to a number properly respecting the locale. Or you might consider using `NSDecimalNumber`s, especially if this is currency (looks like it?). Then `NSDecimalNumber` has a method `+decimalNumberWithString` which also does the right thing for you.

Comment: @Vins This is what I said to do in my answer to your earlier question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913269/ios-replace-char-in-uitextfield

Comment: @rmaddy yep, in fact I have listened your suggestion :)