# Add an international keyboard in ios

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to add my own international keyboard in iphone just like emoji keyboard?
If yes then how it is possible?
Remember i m not asking to enable an international keyboard I am asking to add my own keyboard.
Any suggestions will be highly appreciate.

Regards,

Comment: Do you wish to add a custom keyboard system-wide or just to your own app? You can't add one to the system (at least not with public APIs on non-jailbroken devices).

Comment: I want to add it system-wide not for just my own app

Answer (score 0):

**You can't. The Emoji keyboard is part of the OS, and is simply enabled by setting that defaults key.

There is no supported way on iOS to create your own keyboard and have it be available globally.**

[Create custom international keyboard for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556647/create-custom-international-keyboard-for-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you  lot [Create custom keyboard and configure it on your iPhone.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189287/create-custom-keyboard-and-configure-it-on-your-iphone)

and if you do it with non pulbic API then According to [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?appIdKey=d4f7d769c2abecc664d0dadfed6a67f943442b5e9c87524d4587a95773750cea&path=//appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

- 2.5 Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected
- 2.6 Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected.

There are no public APIs to add an additional keyboard.