# Creating Custom Emojis for iOS Keyboard

Tags: ios, unicode, emoji, custom-keyboard

I have done a research about making Custom Keyboard Extensions for new iOS 9 and adding Custom Emojis to it. 
Everywhere I have looked I found nothing. People say that my problem can't be solved. Even on iOS Forums and other things like that. 
And here comes the KIMOJI app. It has a ton of downloads on the App Store, but noone seems to know how it's built. A set of characters can be copied and sent to other person, seems very easy, but I found nothing on how to do it.

I've read also about Unicode Standards, but I don't see a way how should it be implemented.

Some guy said that even Apple will never accept that kind of application on its Store. Is this true? How could Kimoji get there?

Link to Kimoji App on the App Store (it's not free) [link here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kimoji/id1068019093?mt=8)

Answer (score 4):

No that is wrong. you can implement emoji keyboard at your own. yes for that you need to play with unicode characters. you can get many question regarding emoji keyboard check below link for more detail.

[create-custom-keyboard-and-configure-it-on-your-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189287/create-custom-keyboard-and-configure-it-on-your-iphone)

Moreover you can also find libraries on github,

Example,

1) [AGEmojiKeyboard](https://github.com/ayushgoel/AGEmojiKeyboard)

2) [WUEmoticonsKeyboard](https://github.com/YuAo/WUEmoticonsKeyboard)

3) [iOS-emoji-keyboard](https://github.com/jmascia/iOS-emoji-keyboard)

4) [ISEmojiView](https://github.com/isaced/ISEmojiView)

Note :- If you want to develop your own keyboard without help of libraries on github , you can check logic regarding implementation of keyboard. most probably you need to check how unicode character converted into string and it displays as emoji in text box.

**Edit 1 :-**

[how-to-convert-an-emoji-to-a-unicode-character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635393/ios-5-how-to-convert-an-emoji-to-a-unicode-character)

I hope this info is enough for you to startup building custom emoji keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the early response!
I've checked  these libraries, but none of them have shown the way to convert Custom Images to Unicode Characters (or something different, I don't know) so every newer iOS device can view them..

Comment: @DragosStrugar you need to check logic in their programming file .h and .m file.

Comment: check edited answer with EDIT 1. in this you will find your answer

Comment: it still doesn't answer my question completely.. 
because i want to transfer image to the unicode..

Comment: @DragosStrugar you cant use image as emoji. you must use unicode for emoji's .

Comment: yeah, i get it, but i want to create a custom unicode which will be based on images..

Comment: @DragosStrugar check this https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-create-an-emoji-app-for-iOS-with-original-alternative-symbols

Comment: @BadalShah Of course you can use images to replace emoji, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41001432/5389870 – just not sure whether OP wants to add similar functionality to Kimoji (which appears to simply send images and not rich text) or add custom emoji to the private-use area and display them inline with rich text.

Comment: @BadalShah wait is this just with jailbroken iphones or something or can i actually do this type of customization?? Or maybe i'm misunderstanding and this is just for 3rd party apps or something??

All i want to be able to do is create my own keyboard (or add to the current emoji one) with slackmojis (https://slackmojis.com/)