# Replace iOS app emoji with twitter open source twemoji

Tags: ios, emoji

I want to replace all standard iOS emoji from a UILable or UITextView with twitters open source [twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji).

I can't find any library or documentation to do this in iOS. Does anyone have a solution that does not involve me implementing this from scratch?

The solution needs to be efficient and work offline.

Comment: Ok, great. What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, added question before finishing by accident... See edits.

Comment: @xoudini I've gone through twitters git and searched SO for info on this and found none. If I can't find a ready-made solution, I'm thinking that a category that replaces default emoji with twitter emoji from a vector file could do the trick... But I'll have to leave this for later if that's the case.

Comment: @AndresCanella Alright, I see your point. It'll take a while for me to check through all the emojis but I'll try to give you an answer by tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

The question got me intrigued, and after a bit of searching on how it would be possible to replace **all** standard iOS emoji with a custom set, I noticed that even Twitter's own iOS app doesn't use Twemoji:

[image: tweet]

In the end, I came to the same conclusion as you:

> I can't find any library or documentation to do this in iOS.

#### So, I created [a framework in Swift](https://github.com/xoudini/emojica) for this exact purpose.

It does all the work for you, but if you want to implement your own solution, I'll describe below how to replace **all** standard emoji with Twemoji.

---

#### 1. Document all characters that can be represented as emoji

There are 1126 base characters that have emoji representations, and over a thousand additional representations formed by sequences. Although most base characters are confined to six [Unicode blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block), all but one of these blocks are mixed with non-emoji characters and/or unassigned code points. The remaining base characters outside these blocks are scattered across various other blocks.

My implementation simply declares the UTF-32 code points for these characters, as the `value` property of `UnicodeScalar` is exactly this.

#### 2. Check whether a character is an emoji

In Swift, a `String` contains a collection of `Character` objects, each of which represent a single [extended grapheme cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html). An extended grapheme cluster is a sequence of Unicode scalars that together represent one<sup>1</sup> human-readable character, which is helpful since you can loop through the `Character`s of a string and handling them based on the `UnicodeScalar`s they contain (rather than [looping through the UTF-16 values of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23397279/5389870)).

To identify whether a `Character` is an emoji, only the first `UnicodeScalar` is significant, so comparing this value to your table of emoji characters is enough. However, I'd also recommend checking if the `Character` contains a [Variation Selector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block)), and if it does, make sure that it's VS16 – otherwise the character shouldn't be presented as emoji.

Extracting the `UnicodeScalar`s from a `Character` requires a tiny hack:

```
let c: Character = "A"
let scalars = String(c).unicodeScalars
```

#### 3. Convert the code points into the correct format

[Twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) images are named according to their corresponding code points<sup>2</sup>, which makes sense. So, the next step is to convert the `Character` into a string equivalent to the image name:

```
let codePoint = String("").unicodeScalars.first!.value  // 128579
let imageName = String(codePoint, radix: 16)              // "1f643"
```

Great, but this won't work for [flags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Indicator_Symbol) or [keycaps](http://emojipedia.org/keycap-asterisk/), so we'll have to modify our code to take those into account:

```
let scalars = String("").unicodeScalars
let filtered = scalars.filter{ $0.value != 0xfe0f }       // Remove VS16 from variants, including keycaps.
let mapped = filtered.map{ String($0.value, radix: 16) }
let imageName = mapped.joined(separator: "-")             // "1f1e7-1f1ea"
```

#### 4. Replace the emoji in the string

In order to replace the emoji in a given `String`, we'll need to use `NSMutableAttributedString` for storing the original string, and replace the emoji with `NSTextAttachment` objects containing the corresponding Twemoji image.

```
let originalString = ""

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalString)

for character in originalString.characters {
    // Check if character is emoji, see section 2.
    ...

    // Get the image name from the character, see section 3.
    let imageName = ...

    // Safely unwrapping to make sure the image exists.
    if let image = UIImage(named: imageName) {
        let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        attachment.image = image

        // Create an attributed string from the attachment.
        let twemoji = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)

        // Get the range of the character in attributedString.
        let range = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: String(character))

        // Replace the emoji with the corresponding Twemoji.
        attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: twemoji)
    }
}
```

To display the resulting attributed string, just set it as the `attributedText` property of a `UITextView`/`UILabel`.

Note that the above method doesn't take into account [zero-width joiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) or [modifier sequences](http://blog.emojipedia.org/2015-the-year-of-emoji-diversity/), but I feel like this answer is already too long as it stands.

---

<sup>1. There is a quirk with the `Character` type that interprets a sequence of joined regional indicator symbols as one object, despite containing a theoretically unlimited amount of Unicode  scalars. Try `"".characters.count` in a playground.</sup>

<sup>2. The naming pattern varies slightly when it comes to zero-width joiners and variation selectors, so it's easier to strip these out of the image names – [see here.](https://github.com/xoudini/emojica#compatible-image-sets)</sup>