# Replacing system emoji with custom emoji on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, label, emoji, messenger

I want to replace the system emoji as a user is typing out with my own custom emoji image. I know Facebook Messenger is able to do this on their app so I'm curious how does this work? Their app itself can even turn on/off their own custom emojis. Is it just a custom font?

Here's a link of how it's working:
http://www.idigitaltimes.com/how-turn-facebook-messenger-emoji-company-adds-1500-new-emoji-latest-update-not-538169

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace iOS app emoji with twitter open source twemoji](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663230/replace-ios-app-emoji-with-twitter-open-source-twemoji)