# How do i display an image as a emoji in swift?

Tags: ios, unicode, emoji

I am a relatively new programmer trying to learn ios and I am struggling to figure out how to convert the images i have on my keyboard (emojis) displayed in the message when pressed on.Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Are you using a system keyboard? Do you want to display them in a `UITextField` ? Not really sure what your problem is as emojis can be used directly in a String. `let emoji = ""`

Comment: Yes i am using the system keybaord. The problem is I am using my own emoji's created as images in an xcassets file so I am not sure how to display those

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace iOS app emoji with twitter open source twemoji](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663230/replace-ios-app-emoji-with-twitter-open-source-twemoji)

Answer (score -1):

I'm strongly recommend to you to use instead of UImageView the UILabel. You can set `Autoshrink` to`Minimum Font Scale` / `Minimum Font Size`, then set the `font.pointSize` to something really big like 100 / 200 what ever. Then your emoji text will stretched to maximum fontSize to fit UILabel frame size